# Cannot resolve method 'read' in 'JsonPath'

Tags: java, json, gradle, jsonpath

I currently have a gradle project where I have a line `implementation "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0"` in my build.gradle file. In my code, I have an import statement `import org.springframework.data.web.JsonPath;`, but when I actually use the JsonPath e.g. `obj.put("key", JsonPath.read(jsonStr, "key1.key2.key3.key4"));`, the read method appears as red in my IDE saying that it "Cannot resolve method 'read' in 'JsonPath'". I have tried refreshing gradle dependencies and closing/opening the IDE/window but nothing works - any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this

```
import org.springframework.data.web.JsonPath;
```

use this

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
```

Read this [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/latest/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html) to know more about available methods.

Hope this helps.